# How can I classify data into multiple categories using Naive Bayes?

Tags: python, naivebayes

I am trying to classify sentences into various sentiments(there are eight of them), but I get this error when I run my code. Sorry, I'm really new to Python, so I'm not exactly sure what is happening here.

```
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-40fb2c79238c> in <module>
      18 test_data = data[4800:]
      19 
--->  20 classfier= nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)
      21 print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_data)) 


  ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py in train(cls, labeled_featuresets, estimator)
204         # Count up how many times each feature value occurred, given
205         # the label and featurename.
--> 206         for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
207             label_freqdist[label] += 1
208             for fname, fval in featureset.items():

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

---

This is my original code:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import random

with open("/Users/mac/Documents/Transcribed.rtf", "rb") as f:
data = f.read().split()

random.shuffle(data)

train_data = data[:1200]
test_data = data[4800:]

classfier= nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)
print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_data))
```

Comment: Show requirements, code, output and/or possible error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or by external link.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the problem is in line 206:

```
  ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py in train(cls, labeled_featuresets, estimator)
204         # Count up how many times each feature value occurred, given
205         # the label and featurename.
--> 206         for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
207             label_freqdist[label] += 1
208             for fname, fval in featureset.items():

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The error says that `labeled_featuresets` as you expect in `for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets`. So what you have to do is to print the content of `labeled_featureset` and see how many dimensions it has.

Comment: I tried that, but I got a name error. Apparently label_featureset is not defined

Comment: It's weird then because it should give you the name error here as well

Comment: Hmm.. but in actual fact I didn't code for line 206 by myself, it was generated by the system. Is there a way I can fix it then?

Comment: No, that means that the error is in your code. Check the shape of the data and go through the process on the paper to see if all the dimensions match